# How to groupby using a list of columns

Tags: python, list, pandas-groupby

I am trying to pass a list of columns into a groupby operation. I've seen a number of solutions but to problems that are more complex than mine. What is the **simplest** way to solve for it?

```
cols = [col1, col2, col3]

df[[cols, 'colx']].groupby([cols], as_index=False).sum()
```

Where 'colx' is a column that sum operates on but is not part of the groupby operation.

*TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'*

The code works when instead of a list, columns are directly passed:

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'colx']].groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

I will be honest I don't know exactly what is happening here but I have some theories.  Lets me show you my thought process here:

```
df[["col_1", "col_2", "col_3"]]
```

This is a slice of df containing a list of columns.

When you pass a list into this syntax using like you did in your first example

```
col_list = ["col_1", "col_2", "col_3"]
df[[col_list]]
```

what you are really saying is

```
df[[["col_1", "col_2", "col_3"]]]
```

Pandas doesn't know how to handle the additional list, thus the error.

So how can I pass a list to a dataframe?

```
df[col_list]
```

This works so could I just pass the list and append it in place?  Something like this:

```
df[col_list.append("col_x")]
```

Nope!  That produces a KeyError:

```
>>> df[col_list.append("col_x")]
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>>   File "C:\Users\dmarienburg\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
>>>     return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>>>   File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>>>   File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>>>   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>>>   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>>>   KeyError: None
```

So the easiest solution is just to append the list prior to slicing the dataframe:

```
col_list = ["col_1", "col_2", "col_3"]
# some other code here
col_list.append("col_x")
df[col_list]
```